# события подключения отключения наушников

Tags: android

```
private class MusicIntentReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG)) {
        int state = intent.getIntExtra("state", -1);
        switch (state) {
        case 0:
            Log.d(TAG, "Headset is unplugged");
            break;
        case 1:
            Log.d(TAG, "Headset is plugged");
            break;
        default:
            Log.d(TAG, "I have no idea what the headset state is");
        }
    }
}
```

}

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG);
registerReceiver(myReceiver, filter);
```

С помощью такой конструкции я отслеживаю подключение отключение наушников. С подключение проблем нем, в `state` приходит 1. Проблема в том, что мне нужно отлавливать только само **событие отключения**  наушников, а в `state` приходит 0 время от времени когда наушники не подключены.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

К примеру, можете при подключении, `state = 1` ставить флаг, что наушники подключены и когда приходит `state = 0` смотреть, подключены ли наушники в данный момент:

```
boolean isHSConnected = false;
...
switch (state) {
    case 0:
        if(isHSConnected) {
            //
            Log.d(TAG, "Headset is unplugged");
            isHSConnected = false;
        }
        break;
    case 1:
        Log.d(TAG, "Headset is plugged");
        isHSConnected = true;
        break;
```