# Событие подключения микрофона

Tags: android, broadcast-receiver, android-broadcastreceiver, headset

есть прозрачный [код](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/522861/%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%83%D1%88%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2) для определения подключения/отключения наушников, подскажите, как определить факт подключения внешнего микрофона (наличие микрофона у подключенной гарнитуры)

```
private class MusicIntentReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG)) {
        int state = intent.getIntExtra("state", -1);
        switch (state) {
        case 0:
            Log.d(TAG, "Headset is unplugged");
            break;
        case 1:
            Log.d(TAG, "Headset is plugged");
            break;
        default:
            Log.d(TAG, "I have no idea what the headset state is");
        }
    }
}

IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG);
registerReceiver(myReceiver, filter);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы так же можете это получить из `intent`:

```
int mic = intent.getIntExtra("microphone", -1);
switch (mic ) {
    case 0:
        Log.d(TAG, "No microphone");
        break;
    case 1:
        Log.d(TAG, "Headset with microphone");
        break;
    default:
        Log.d(TAG, "Something wrong");
        break;
}
Log.d(TAG, intent.getStringExtra("name", "no name"));
```

Comment: Подскажите еще, пожалуйста, как подобную информацию можно было найти на https://developer.android.com.  После вашего ответа хватило фантазии в режиме debug посмотреть mExtras для intent.

Comment: @x555xx В поиске на сайте ввести  ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG microphone, и  по первой ссылке найти https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG . Если просто ввести в поиске ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG, то по первой ссылке уже этого не найти, только по второй :)

Comment: Большое спасибо! разобрался)