# Почему показывает Toast при запуске приложения?

Tags: android, broadcast-receiver

```
Это мой класс CustomReceiver
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String intentAction = intent.getAction();
    if(intentAction != null){
        String toastMessage = "unknown intent message";
        switch(intentAction){
            case Intent.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED:
                toastMessage = "Power connected!";
                break;
            case Intent.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED:
                toastMessage = "Power disconnected!";
                break;
            case Intent.ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG:
                toastMessage = "Headphones connected";
                break;
        }
        Toast.makeText(context, toastMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Это мой класс MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String ACTION_CUSTOM_BROADCAST = BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".ACTION_CUSTOM_BROADCAST";
    CustomReceiver mReceiver = new CustomReceiver();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
        filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED);
        filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED);
        filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG);
        this.registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
    }
```

Почему когда я просто запускаю приложение, без подключения наушников все равно Toast "Headphoes Connected" показывается ? !

Comment: Есть такие рассылки, которые при регистрации сразу присылают текущее состояние, а потом оповещают об изменениях - вот это одна из них.

Comment: то есть это нормально, код правильный ? Просто, он так работает ?

Comment: Да, это нормально. Так сделано чтобы нам не приходилось дополнительно проверять подключены ли уши сейчас. Просто регистрируем приёмник и в нём запускаем логику действия при подключении и отключении. Вы же в курсе, что `ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG` приходит и при отключении? Вот тут пример кода если что: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/522861/11515